# How to measure performance of asynchronous method?

Tags: swift, unit-testing

I've written a method `loadCountries()` that performs asynchronous file loading upon calling and then notifies its output that the work is done. I'm trying to measure this method's performance in my tests but I can't figure out how to handle asynchronous operations without callbacks with `measure` block.

I found out there are `startMeasuring()` and `stopMeasuring()` methods that allow to manually set entry and end points for the test. I tried to call the latter in my output mock:

```
let output = InteractorOutputMock()
output.onDisplay = { _ in
    self.stopMeasuring()
}

let interactor = PremiumLocationsChooserInteractor()
interactor.output = output

measureMetrics([.wallClockTime], automaticallyStartMeasuring: false) {
    self.startMeasuring()
    interactor.loadCountries()
}
```

But the code still finishes in 0 secs. How should I approach this issue?

UPDATE:

I tried using expectations as well, but ran into problem. I can neither call it inside the measure block nor outside of it. The former looks like the following and causes the code to wait in the first iteration of `measure`:

```
let outputCalledExpectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "Output   hasn't been called")
outputCalledExpectation.expectedFulfillmentCount = 10 // need to fullfill it 10 times since this is how much measure block is called
let output = InteractorOutputMock()
output.onDisplay = { _ in
    self.stopMeasuring() // called only once
    outputCalledExpectation.fulfill()
}

let interactor = PremiumLocationsChooserInteractor()
interactor.output = output

measureMetrics([.wallClockTime], automaticallyStartMeasuring: false) {
    startMeasuring()
    interactor.loadCountries()
    wait(for: [outputCalledExpectation], timeout: 5.0) // then stack here
}
```

And if I try to move the wait method outside of the block, I get exception `-stopMeasuring is only supported from a block passed to -measure...Block:`

```
measureMetrics([.wallClockTime], automaticallyStartMeasuring: false) {
    startMeasuring()
    interactor.loadCountries()
}
wait(for: [outputCalledExpectation], timeout: 5.0) // get exception here
```

Comment: Use an XCTExpectation.

Comment: I tried different ways with expectations, but none worked for me. 

Because the measure block is called 10 times, the expectation fulfillment count needs to be set to 10. In this case waiting for expectation blocks the execution in the first iteration. And if I wait outside of the block, I get exception stating `-stopMeasuring is only supported from a block passed to -measure...Block:`.

Comment: Well, XCTExpectation is how you do asynchronous testing. You have not shown any real code, and none of the sketch that you have shown uses XCTExpectation, so I have no idea what _you_ are doing.

Comment: So regardless of the test, how your code knows when loading on the background is done and you can use whatever `interactor.loadCountries()` produced?

Comment: When loading is done, the interactor calls `displayCountries(with:)` on its output, which is usually presenter in terms of VIPER. In my mock, I just need to make sure this methods is called.

Comment: @matt I updated the post to show how I tried to use expectations.

Answer (score 1):

I use this extension for measuring, works like a charm for me.

```swift
extension XCTestCase {
  func measureAsync(
    timeout: TimeInterval = 2.0,
    for block: @escaping () async throws -> Void,
    file: StaticString = #file,
    line: UInt = #line
  ) {
    measureMetrics(
      [.wallClockTime],
      automaticallyStartMeasuring: true
    ) {
      let expectation = expectation(description: "finished")
      Task { @MainActor in
        do {
          try await block()
          expectation.fulfill()
        } catch {
          XCTFail(error.localizedDescription, file: file, line: line)
          expectation.fulfill()
        }
      }
      wait(for: [expectation], timeout: timeout)
    }
  }
}
```